# IEnumerable as constructor parameter when list is kept in class

Tags: c#, list, parameter-passing

If I want to store the list that the class is being passed as a parameter, what parameter type should I use?

Should I take an IEnumerable and do something like `Items = items.ToList().AsReadOnly()`? But how do I avoid superfluous copies? What if the list was created inside the constructor call, that's definitely a `ToList()` too many then.

In C++ I would have a non-reference parameter to make sure a copy of the list is passed, but AFAIK in C# that's not possible.

One example I have in mind is an event arguments class that contains a list of something, that is also the current state of the invoking class. The lists should not change after they have been passed to the various event handlers.

Creating a copy inside the constructor is fine when is is called like this:

```
SomethingHappened?.Invoke(this, new CustomEventArgs(_items));
```

But when it is called like this, a unnecessary copy is made:

```
SomethingHappened?.Invoke(this, new CustomEventArgs(new List { item1, item2 }));
```

Comment: Your class probably shouldn't know that it's working with a copy. What your class does with the List is up to your class. What is your goal? You could, for example, write a constructor that takes an `IReadOnlyList<T>` and pass the list to the constructor by calling `AsReadOnly()` on the original List instance if your class doesn't need to change the list. You'll have the original instance outside of that class and you have a read-only reference inside the class.

Comment: @ewerspej The class takes ownership of the list. So it needs to make sure the calling class doesn't change it afterwards.

Comment: So it's in reverse? I recommend you add that information more explicitly to the question. In that case, it should be sufficient to make a copy. Can you elaborate on the scenario, show a code example?

Comment: @ewerspej: I added an example.

Comment: There's virtually no difference between those two scenarios. From the point of view of the constructor, those statements are the same thing. Therefore, you'll have to make a copy if you want data integrity, because you can't know how the constructor is called. You could technically solve this by passing in another argument that determines whether a copy should be made or not, which then transfers the responsibility (and knowledge) from the callee to the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to modify the list which is passed in to your constructor in your class, then you could define the parameter as an `IReadOnlyList<T>` and pass it by calling `AsReadOnly()` on the original list. You'll still use the same list, but `AsReadOnly()` provides a wrapper which prevents modification, as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.asreadonly):

```cs
public class YourClass
{
    private IReadOnlyList<SomeType> yourList;

    public YourClass(IReadOnlyList<SomeType> list)
    {
        yourList = list;
    }
}
```

Then call the constructor as follows:

```cs
var someList = new List<SomeType>();

var yourClassInstance = new YourClass(someList.AsReadOnly());
```

You can still change the original list reference and it will be reflected in the read-only reference, since they're actually accessing the same list, but you won't be able to modify the list inside `YourClass`.

Alternatively, if you cannot call `AsReadOnly()` on the outside, then you need to call it inside your constructor, which would technically allow your class to make modifications before storing the read-only reference:

```cs
public class YourClass
{
    private IReadOnlyList<SomeType> yourList;

    public YourClass(IList<SomeType> list)
    {
        yourList = list.AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```

If you do need to modify the passed list after all, you'll need to make a copy, by which `YourClass` would then take ownership of the copy:

```cs
public class YourClass
{
    private IList<SomeType> yourList;

    public YourClass(IList<SomeType> list)
    {
        yourList = new List<T>(list);
    }
}
```

Since the callee cannot know on its own whether a copy should be made, you could add an optional flag to the constructor to transfer the responsibility to the caller:

```cs
public class YourClass
{
    private IList<SomeType> yourList;

    public YourClass(IList<SomeType> list, bool makeCopy = false)
    {
        yourList = makeCopy ? new List<T>(list) : list;
    }
}
```

This way, the caller must decide whether a copy is required:

```cs
var someList = new List<SomeType>();

//Make a copy explicitly
var yourClassInstance1 = new YourClass(someList, true);

//Do not make a copy
var yourClassInstance2 = new YourClass(new List<SomeType>{ object1, object2 });
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there would be a better solution, but I guess I'm just spoiled by using C++.

Comment: @gartenriese I'm not aware of another solution for this particular problem for class objects. There are no `const` arguments (in C# the `const` keyword is a *compile-time* keyword) nor can you implicitly make a copy of a reference type instance by passing it as a value. This only works with value types, such as structs.